# How to add a custom Sling binding?

Tags: jsp, aem, sling

I want to extend Sling bindings with a custom object, so it'll be available in all JSP files without an extra effort. I'm implementing [`BindingsValuesProvider` OSGi service](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SLING/Adding+New+Scripting+Variables), like this (it's not an actual code, but similar enough):

```
@Component
@Service
public class ContentBranchBindingProvider implements BindingsValuesProvider {

    @Override
    public void addBindings(Bindings bindings) {
        final Resource resource = (Resource) bindings.get("resource");
        final String[] splitPath = StringUtils.split(resource.getPath(), '/');
        bindings.put("contentBranch", splitPath[1]);
    }
}
```

I expect that the `contentBranch` binding will be available as scripting variable in JSP:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
Your content branch is: ${contentBranch}
```

However, above JSP doesn't output the content branch but:

> Your content branch is:

I used debugger to see that my `addBindings()` method is called and puts a proper value into `bindings` map. What can I do to have it available as `${contentBranch}` in JSP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sling Bindings are not automatically available as scripting variables. There is [a plan to change it](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-3217) to change it but in the current version of Sling they are not.

Sling uses [`<sling:defineObjects/>`](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-scripting-jsp-taglib.html#defineobjects) to copy its own bindings to the page context and therefore expose them as scripting variables, but it won't work for the custom values like `contentBranch`.

However, one of the scripting variables defined by the `<sling:defineObjects/>` is `bindings`, so you may access the new value like this:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
Your content branch is: ${bindings.contentBranch}
```

Alternatively, consider writing [a custom `defineObjects`](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/bundles/scripting/jsp-taglib/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/jsp/taglib/DefineObjectsTag.java) tag.

Also, Sling bindings are available as scripting values in [Sightly](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly.html) without any extra effort:

```
Your content branch is: ${contentBranch}
```